# How to set "secure" attribute of the cookies used by Google Analytics Global Site Tag (gtag.js)?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm using Google Analytics Global Site Tag (gtag.js) tracking code on my Github Pages. The following tracking code is copy-and-pasted as the first item into the `<HEAD>` of every webpage I want to track (I replaced my own tracking ID with `GA_MEASUREMENT_ID`):

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

Recently, when I open my Github Pages site with Firefox browser, the console logs the following warning messages:

`Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite`

`Cookie “_gid” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[The gtag.js settings can be customized](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config). Specifically, we can set [`cookie_flags` field](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#cookie_flags) to solve the issue.

In the tracking code, the line

```js
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
```

should be changed to

```js
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure' });
```

to fix the issue.

So the whole tracking code should be the following (Don't forget to replace the two occurrences of `GA_MEASUREMENT_ID` with your own tracking ID):

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure' });
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE** (Thanks to [@RichDeBourke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011984/rich-debourke) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569419/how-to-set-secure-attribute-of-the-cookies-used-by-google-analytics-global-sit/62569420?noredirect=1#comment113116301_62569420)):

The console can still log a warning message like the following:

```
Cookie “_ga” has been rejected for invalid domain.
```

To fix the issue, [cookie domain of gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#cookie_domain) needs to be configured. So the line mentioned in the original answer

```js
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', { cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure' });
```

should be further edited to

```js
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  cookie_domain: 'YOUR_GITHUB_PAGES_DOMAIN',
  cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure',
});
```

Then, the whole tracking code is the following (Don't forget to replace `YOUR_GITHUB_PAGES_DOMAIN` with your own GitHub pages domain (which is, typically, `<username>.github.io` where `<username>` is your actual GitHub user name) and the two occurrences of `GA_MEASUREMENT_ID` with your own tracking ID):

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
    cookie_domain: 'YOUR_GITHUB_PAGES_DOMAIN',
    cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure',
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @ Gorisanson — Thanks for the post. I too was getting the message about cookies being soon rejected and your info about adding *cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'* eliminated those warnings. Then I started getting a warning on Firefox: *Cookie “_ga” has been rejected for invalid domain* (Chrome didn’t show the warning). Adding a cookie domain field eliminated the warning. My gtag parameters are now `("config", "GA_MEASUREMENT_ID", { "anonymize_ip": true, "cookie_domain": ".mysite.com", "cookie_flags": "SameSite=None;Secure" })` – *I use the anonymize option to provide a little more privacy*.

Comment: This does not seem to be working in GA4:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629791/how-do-i-track-traffic-from-3rd-party-websites-in-iframes-in-ga4

Comment: @ChrisScott I checked that it was working well in GA4 too :)

Answer (score 11):

I just set up a Google Analytics 4 property, and was getting the same warning in Firefox console as in the original question:

> Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite”
> attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure”
> attribute. ...

But adding the `cookie_flags` as an option to the `gtag('config', ...)` invoke was not working for me.

Browser cookie storage revealed that the GA cookies were indeed not being stored with as secure.

I was able to fix the problem by adding an additional `gtag('set', ...)`, like so:

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('set', {cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'});
  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

Perhaps something has changed with Google Analytics API?

The [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id#cookie_flags) seems to indicate that `set` is how you should be passing `cookie_flags`.

Comment: Setting the flags in 'config' works for me. Setting the flags in 'set' also works for me (as long as the 'set' precedes the 'config', as it does in this answer). Setting the flags in 'set' AFTER 'config' does not work for me.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this using purely Google Tag Manager code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

For the people using Google Tag Manager, you can set the SameSite attribute for the Google Analytics tracking cookies within the GTM Configuration.

1. In [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/), go to **Variables**
2. Find your GA Tracking ID variable, and click to edit
3. Under *More Settings* -> *Fields to set*

   - Add the Field Name `cookieFlags`
   - Set the Value to whatever SameSite value you want, e.g. `samesite=none;secure`
     [image: Setting SameSite attributes for cookieFlags]
4. Save and publish a new version of your GTM configuration.

If done correctly this should resolve the browser warnings you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) npm package:

```js
ReactGA.initialize("UA-XXXXXX-1", { gaOptions: { cookieFlags: "SameSite=None;Secure" } });
```