# How do I track traffic from 3rd-party websites in iframes in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics

In Universal Analytics, I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569419/how-to-set-secure-attribute-of-the-cookies-used-by-google-analytics-global-sit/62569420?noredirect=1#comment113116301_62569420) you need to set some cookie flags to have iframed content on third party websites tracked. with:

```
gtag('set', {cookie_flags: 'SameSite=None;Secure'});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in GA4. Or at least, I don't see the iframed traffic in real-time stats. I do, however, see iframed content in UA real-time stats. I'm using the same tracking tag (linked) on the same website. Just doesn't seem to be working in UA4.

Comment: Have you [checked the cookies right in your browser](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/)? If the cookie attributes were set well, the gtag.js tracking code would not be the problem. Maybe you should look into GA4 events settings? I don't know.. I'm not an expert of GA4..